# Open in new windows with PHP

Tags: php, target, new-window

I search about open in new windows with PHP code , but I don't know how to adapt the code:

1)

```
<a href="<?php echo $value['link'] ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-large appico-content-more"><?php echo $value['readmore']
```

2)

```
if(isset($value['showlink']) and $value['showlink']=='yes' ) echo '<a href="' . $value['link'] . '">';
```

I need that link open in new windows.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="link" target="_blank">link</a>
```

set target="_blank"

Answer (score 0):

add `target="_blank"` to the a tag.

```
<a href="<?php echo $value['link'] ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-large appico-content-more" target="_blank">
```

and

```
if(isset($value['showlink']) and $value['showlink']=='yes' ) echo '<a href="' . $value['link'] . '" target="_blank">';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , the first code fix the problem in mod_sp_smart_slider